# Opencv homography in java

Tags: java, opencv, homography

i am new about opencv in java. I need to homography, but i dont know how i do. I have   square four coordinates. Like this picture. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/91i7x.jpg)
How can I do like step 2. Can you write only homography basic codes in java ? Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [OpenCV: What are the parameters for the WarpPerspective function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25766543/opencv-what-are-the-parameters-for-the-warpperspective-function)

Comment: This is the same question as your [previous one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44994446/fix-irregular-image-in-opencv-java#comment76969740_44994446). Please don't ask duplicate questions. If you are not getting the answers you are looking for, improve the question. If you feel the duplicate I marked on the other question is not correct, clarify the question and explain why the duplicate doesn't work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fix irregular image in opencv java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44994446/fix-irregular-image-in-opencv-java)